# How to set a fragment of the MMIO space in a different cache attribute?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'd like to map the whole MMIO with `ioremap() or pci_iomap()` and then set as WC only few pages.

- `set_memory_wc()` uses `__pa()` to convert the virt to phys address but that is invalid for MMIO space.
- Unfortunately `ioremap_change_attr()` is a wrapper for `set_memory_*()` functions

**Question:**

- **Is there such a function for mem space mapped with those functions?**

Source: https://kernelnewbies.kernelnewbies.narkive.com/qaX6sjqI/ioremap-addresses

Comment: Why do you need this? In any case in kernel there is one (or two?) driver which does this weirdness. Grep sources for `ioremap_uc`. Read this code: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/video/fbdev/aty/atyfb_base.c#L3427

Comment: To avoid using 2 different BARs for registers and small buffer. Unfortunately `arch_phys_wc_add()` uses MTRR and doesn't do anything for PAT enabled CPU. Unless I write a custom `ioremap()`, I don't think that's possible. Thanks tho!

Comment: I see, I would avoid such design and consider is bad. You see, only couple of drivers in Linux kernel have this kind of weirdness. Another solution is to have a bar size twice bigger than the bigger part you need. Then in the PCI quirks you re-split it with proper alignment. But it is still bad designed hardware.

Comment: Understood. Any details about what does "bad" mean? Bad for who? If that's bad, what is the alternative to achieve the same result?

Comment: Means that you have to apply to different rules to the PCI resource. And this become exactly an issue you are trying to fix. My point, don't create the issue in the first place.

Comment: Roger, I'll use 2BARS ;) thanks!